# How do I use the "next" color in the palette without specifying it manually?

Tags: python, colors, seaborn, scatter-plot

I am drawing a few scatter plots in seaborn and they all come out with blue points:

[image]

I would like to change the color of the points. I found some rather complicated solutions where you can specify the color manually, but this is not what I want.

**I don't care which color it is, it should just be different from blue and be one of the colors of the current palette** to keep the visuals pleasing.

Is there something like `start_with_palette_color=1` (default 0) in:

```
sns.scatterplot(data=tips, x="total_bill", y="tip", start_with_palette_color=1)
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current palette can be viewed with *color_palette()* when called without parameters. It returns a list of RGB tuples that represent the palette's colors.

*scatterplot()* accepts the named parameter `color=` to specify any color.

```
import seaborn as sns
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
# first scatter plot with default color
sns.scatterplot(data=tips, x="total_bill", y="tip")
# second scatter plot with the next color (array index 1 instead of implicit 0)
sns.scatterplot(data=tips, x="total_bill", y="tip",color=sns.color_palette()[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Anywhere matplotlib accepts a color, you can use `"C{i}"` to get the `i`th color in the current matplotlib cycle, which is probably the easiest way to accomplish this.

For example, "C0". Or "C3".

Comment: Can you give an example? I tried variations of `"C{i}"` and it did not work.